# How to avoid specifying all cache name in ehCache with spring?

Tags: spring, ehcache

I am using Spring Cache in my application and would like to go for ehCache implementation. How can I avoid specifying all the cache names in ehcache.xml?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<ehcache xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://ehcache.org/ehcache.xsd">    

   <defaultCache eternal="true" maxElementsInMemory="100" overflowToDisk="false" />           

   <cache name="test" maxElementsInMemory="10" eternal="true" overflowToDisk="false" />  

</ehcache>
```

I would like to avoid specifying all the cache names here in the XML. Is there a way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With EhCache, you can create all the caches programmatically if desired (i.e. at application startup for example)
It still needs an ehcache.xml with at the minimum a defaultCache defined...but then you can either create a new cache 2 ways:

1 - Based on the defaultCache defined in ehcache.xml:

```
   CacheManager singletonManager = CacheManager.create();
   singletonManager.addCache("testCache");
```

2 - Based on custom settings you want:

```
   //Create a singleton CacheManager using defaults
   CacheManager manager = CacheManager.create();

   //Create a Cache specifying its configuration.
   Cache testCache = new Cache(
   new CacheConfiguration("testCache", maxEntriesLocalHeap)
    .memoryStoreEvictionPolicy(MemoryStoreEvictionPolicy.LFU)
    .eternal(false)
    .timeToLiveSeconds(60)
    .timeToIdleSeconds(30)
    .diskExpiryThreadIntervalSeconds(0)
    .persistence(new PersistenceConfiguration().strategy(Strategy.LOCALTEMPSWAP)));

   //Remember to add the cache to the cacheManager: The cache is not usable until it has been added.
   manager.addCache(testCache);
```

More at: http://ehcache.org/documentation/code-samples#adding-and-removing-caches-programmatically and http://ehcache.org/documentation/code-samples#creating-caches-programmatically.